# I keep getting an error when trying to create this matrix?

Tags: java, computer-science

I need to create two matrices with user input being the dimensions, and then multiply them. I'm stuck on filling the matrices with random numbers, keeps saying I can't convert from double to int[], screenshot below.

[image]

I'm a beginner to programming, all my knowledge comes from college classes, intro to cs, cs 2, and just started data structures.

Comment: Why are you trying to cast an `int` (What is returned by `Math.random() * (x+1)`) to an `int[]`?

Comment: Next time instead of attaching the image post the code. As it would be easy for others to find the mistake

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: Please state the errors. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. In addition, the text cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Comment: alright i will do that for next time, this was my first time using this site but it wont be my last :).

Comment: Hey guys, how would I print the matrix? this is the code I have,                   
               for (int row=0; row<a.length; row++) {
  for(int column=0; column<a.length; column++) {
   System.out.println(a[row][column]);
   
  }                                                                                                                      It prints the numbers in the array but it's not in a structured row column, it just prints the number one after the other.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
a[indexOne][indexTwo] = (int)(Math.random() * (x+1));
```

To learn more about matrix check [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-2-d-array-matrix-java/)

Comment: thanks, its working but how would i print it? I tried System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a + b), but it gives answers like this: [I@7d4991ad[I@7d4991ad[I@7d4991ad[I@28d93b], also how would I print it out like an actual 50X50 matrix? thank you senpai